# Fine Print of Egorov's Theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Egorov's theorem in my textbook requires that the function to be define on a set with finite measure. Why is this necessary, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Take e.g. $f_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}$. Then $f_n \rightarrow 0$ pointwise, but there is no set $E$ of (Lebesgue) measure $|E| < 1/2$, so that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ uniformly on $\Bbb{R} \setminus E$ (why?).

EDIT: If you look at the proof (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem#Proof ), then "continuity of $\mu$ from above" is used, e.g. that $\mu(\bigcap_n E_{n,k}) = \lim_n \mu(E_{n,k})$ (here we also use $E_{n+1,k} \subset E_{n,k}$ for all $n,k$).

But this is in general not true if the measure space is of infinite measure, e.g. $|\bigcap_n [n,\infty)| = 0$, but $|[n, \infty)| = \infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: One question in my textbook is to generalise the theorem such that it applies to set of infinite measure. Is this possible, please?

Comment: That depends upon which generalization you have in mind. The above example shows that you cannot just drop the requirement of finite measure. If you know $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ (instead of only pointwise convergence), then there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$, such that the conclusion of Egorov is true for this subsequence. But in general (i.e. without taking a subsequence), $f_n = \chi_{[n, n+ \frac{1}{n}]}$ is a counterexample.